# google maps directions service geolocation and address input jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I've put together a simple jquery mobile map that uses google maps and the directions service.  It all works, except if a user inputs an address (either start or destination) without entering the city the results are extremely far out.  Google directions will return an area somewhere in another province or even in the US.

I thought the directions would be based off the lat long origin and it would attempt to use local address geocoding?  How can I improve the input so the user can get more accurate results based on just entering an address?

Below is my code for it:

```
 $(document).on("pageinit", "#map_page", function () {
            initialize();
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#getDirectionsSubmit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            calculateRoute();
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#getCurrentLoc', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            findCurrentPosition();
        });

        var directionDisplay,
            directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
            map;
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        function initialize() {
            // set the default center of the map
            var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(55.1669513, -118.8031093);
            // set route options (draggable means you can alter/drag the route in the map)
            var rendererOptions = { draggable: true };
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

            //updateMapSize(mapCenter);
            // set the display options for the map
            var myOptions = {
                mapTypeControl: false,
                zoom: 12,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: mapCenter
            }
            // add the map to the map placeholder
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            // bind the map to the directions
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            // point the directions to the container for the direction details
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));         

        }

        function notFound(msg) {
            alert('Could not find your location :(')
        }

        function findCurrentPosition() {   
            // start the geolocation API
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                // when geolocation is available on your device, run this function
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundYou, notFound);
            } else {
                // when no geolocation is available, alert this message
                alert('Geolocation not supported or not enabled.');
            }
        }

        function foundYou(position) {
            // convert the position returned by the geolocation API to a google coordinate object
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            // then try to reverse geocode the location to return a human-readable address
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    // if the geolocation was recognized and an address was found
                    if (results[0]) {
                        // add a marker to the map on the geolocated point
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,                   
                            map: map
                        });
                        // compose a string with the address parts
                        var address = results[0].address_components[1].long_name + ' ' + results[0].address_components[0].long_name + ', ' + results[0].address_components[3].long_name
                        // set the located address to the link, show the link and add a click event handler

                            // onclick, set the geocoded address to the start-point formfield
                            $('#from').text(address);
                            $('#from').val(address);
                            // call the calcRoute function to start calculating the route        
                    }
                } else {
                    // if the address couldn't be determined, alert and error with the status message
                    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                }
            });
        }

        function calculateRoute() {
            var selectedtravelMode = $('#mode option:selected').val();
            // alert(selectedtravelMode);
            start = $("#from").val();
                end = $("#to").val();

            if (start == '' || end == '') {
                // cannot calculate route
                $("#results").hide();
                return;
            }
            else {
                var request = {
                    origin: start,
                    destination: end,                    
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode[selectedtravelMode]
                };

                directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        $("#results").show();                   
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#results").hide();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="map_page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Directions Map</h1>
            <a href="http://mysiteaddress/" data-ajax="false" rel="external" id="returnMobile">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" class="ui-content">
            <div>
                <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 300px"></div>
                <div data-role="my-ui-field-contain">
                    <!--<div>
            <label for="mode" class="select">Transportation method:</label>
        </div>-->
                    <div>
                        <select name="select-choice-0" id="mode">
                            <option value="TRANSIT">Public Transit</option>
                            <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
                            <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
                            <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>                
                <div data-role="my-ui-field-contain">
                    <input type="text" id="from" placeholder="From Address" value="" /><button id="getCurrentLoc" data-icon="star">Use Current Location</button>
                </div>
                <div data-role="my-ui-field-contain">
                    <input type="text" id="to" placeholder="To Destination" value="" />
                </div>
                <a data-icon="search" data-role="button" href="#" id="getDirectionsSubmit">Get directions</a>
            </div>
            <div id="results" style="display:none;">
                <div id="directionsPanel"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The directions service uses the information you give it.  If you want it to be "smarter" than that, you need to write code to implement the functionality you want.

Comment: Ok, so I guess that is my question.  What options am I missing to give preference to the city in which the directions were based on?

Comment: There aren't any such options.  You need to write code to do that.

Comment: Great, are there examples of this?  I cant' seem to find any

Comment: Not that I know of (which doesn't mean they don't exist).

Comment: I really don't know where the addresses are currently chosen from.  Normally my experience with google maps online is that if you enter an address it filters the results to your current location.  My code above doesn't do that and if I enter an address without adding the city in there as part of that address google seems to randomly choose a location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this now working.  I added an autocomplete feature into the text input boxes as well as limited the output to the country level which really helped to avoid the incorrect start and end destination issues.

var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'ca'}};